# Storing a List<long> of Prime Numbers

Tags: c#, .net, prime-factoring

I am writing a program to calculate Prime factors and I need the next prime number to see if my input number is divisible. The list of prime number, up to a large enough number, is known. [Example](http://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/10000.txt).

My question is, is it good or bad practice to store a list of first 10,000 prime numbers in my C# code and use it while calculating prime factors?

Comment: why don't you show us the code that you have so that we can logically see what it is you're talking about

Comment: What do you think might be "bad" about it?

Comment: Is it bad on memory or a bad practice to store a HUGE list in code?

Comment: maybe store offsets starting from a base number instead?

Comment: Well it entirely depends on your definition of "huge" and how much memory you have. Unfortunately this question is pretty vague, pretty broad and likely pretty opinion based.

Comment: Reason for down votes please. It's a valid question about best coding practice, I have done my research and asked the opinion of others... I don see what's wrong in this.

Comment: You need a very long list of prime numbers before they would overflow an UInt32...

Comment: ViV, I would rephrase this question to ask for better ways retrieve a list of primes rather than just storing a large amount of numbers in a list

Comment: @ViV SO is not a good place to ask about coding practice, perhaps [programmers.SE] would be a good place, but don't quote me on that as I don't visit it often.

Comment: @ViV 10 000 numbers is not a "huge" list at all, it's very tiny even. A long is 64 bit, so 10 000 long is 640kbit or 80kbyte. Even 1 million would only be 8 mégabytes.

Comment: @DavidG this question is a poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6490#6490 Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: @gnat That link says "algorithm and data structure concepts" is on-topic for P.SE which this question (kind-of) is. Anyway, you're way more active on there than me so I'll just agree! Either way, it's not on-topic here either :)

Comment: @DavidG This question is *on-topic* for Programmers, yes, but it's not good enough to migrate. In its current state, there simply isn't enough information; any answer we tried to give would simply be a blind guess as to what the OP is after or should be using instead, as the two answers already posted here clearly show.

Comment: Why is anyone refuting that this is programming related? It's very very obviously related to programming. Sheesh people......

Comment: @JoePhilllips: I don't see any comments here that claim the question is not programming related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could possibly store offsets instead:

If your primes are: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43

then your offsets would be (with base=2): 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 6, 2, 6, 4, 2, ...

Basically the offsets are just the difference between a prime and the next prime in the list. Mathematically speaking, I'm not sure if this would really save much space but it might be worth investigating. You could most likely use a smaller datatype to cover the same number space.

Here's an interesting read on the "prime gap" which shows you that the difference in primes stays relatively small throughout very large primes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap

If you're only storing 10,000 primes, this is pointless. Just store them or calculate them.

Comment: That's Great. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Remember that storing the gaps in `int` values won't save you any space (for the first 10,000 primes) and will make your calculations much slower.

Comment: Right, I would not store them as `int` if you want to achieve any space savings. They would have to be stored as compressed bits or something (huffman coding perhaps)

Comment: Which would increase the computational expense by a fairly large amount. In this situation I think that storing the raw numbers is significantly better, probably in a `HashSet` rather than a `List` though.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is create a boolean function that can return a boolean depending on whether or not the value is a PrimeNumber.

```
private bool IsPrimeNumber(int value)
{
    for(int i = 2; i < value; i++)
    {
        if(value % i == 0)//If the remainder of "value" divided by "i" is equal to 0.
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then I would create the function that determines all the prime factors of a value.

```
private int[] primefactors(int value)
{
    if (value < 0)
    {
        throw new Exception("Value can't be less than 0.");//Make sure value is not less than 0.
    }
    List<int> primefactors = new List<int>();
    for(int i = 2; i < value; i++)
    {
        if (value % i == 0 && IsPrimeNumber(i))//If the remainder of "value" divided by "i" is equal to 0 and "i" is a prime number.
        {
            factors.Add(i);
        }
    }
    return primefactors.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: @DavidG In what way does it not? Please explain.

Comment: The question asked is not how to achieve the list of prime numbers, it's "is it good or bad practice to store a list of first 10,000 prime numbers in my C# code and use it while calculating prime factors".

Comment: I'm giving an alternative practice. Having a huge list is obviously not particularly feasible compared to programmatically determining whether or not numbers are prime numbers.

Comment: @Rariolu: That's just not true at all.  If your goal is to get the nth prime as rapidly as possible and storage space is not a critical factor, then it makes far more sense to store a table of primes than it does to compute them each time you need them.